# Understanding Handwritten digit by computer

Tags: python, image-processing

i would like to  ask you  one question : wanted to implement  a code which clarifies  a picture done by hand ( by pen), let us consider  such image
[image]

it is done by blue pen,  which  should be  converted to  the gray scale image using following code

```
from PIL import Image

user_test = filename
col = Image.open(user_test)
gray = col.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<100 else 255, '1')
bw.save("bw_image.jpg")
bw
img_array = cv2.imread("bw_image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_array = cv2.bitwise_not(img_array)
print(img_array.size)
plt.imshow(img_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
img_size = 28
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

idea is that i  am  taking image from camera directly, but  it is losing structure of digit and comes only  empty and black picture, like this
[image]

therefore computer can't understand  which digit it is  and neural networks fails to predict its label correctly, could you please tell me which transformation should i apply in order to  detect  this  image much more precisely ?

```
edit :
```

i have  apply following code

```
from PIL import Image

user_test = filename
col = Image.open(user_test)
gray = col.convert('L')
plt.hist(img_array)
plt.show()
```

and  got 
[image]

Comment: Try plotting a histogram of the values of gray before you threshold the values. This should show you if your threshold is roughly reasonable.

Comment: how  can  i  automatically apply  histogram in case of threshold?

Comment: Do the histogram *before* the threshold. You want to see how many 0's,1's...,255's. Perhaps most of the 3 you have in the image is over 100 in terms of the value of the bit. It becomes 1's after your threshold...therefore by looking at the histogram you'll get a better idea of where the threshold should be.

Comment: If you look carefully at your histogram, it looks like the mass of your pixel intensities are way above 100 (between 230-250ish), which is why most of your image is white after thresholding. You can try denoising like one of the answers here suggests, but perhaps also limit your histogram to values between 200-250 and get some more bins in there....

Comment: i have tried following code : bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<200 else 250, '1') but i am getting black image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here, and you can methodically address them.
First of all you're having an issue with thresholding properly.

As I suggested in earlier comments, you can easily see why your original thresholding was unsuccessful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm

im = Image.open('whatever_path_you_choose.jpg').convert("L")
im = np.asarray(im)
plt.hist(im.flatten(), bins=np.arange(255));
```

Looking at the image you gave:

[image]

Clearly the threshold should be somewhere between 100-200, not as in your original code. Also note that this distribution isn't very bimodal - so I'm not sure otsu's method would work well here.

If we eyeball it (this can be tuned), we can see that thresholding at 145-ish gives decent results in terms of segmentation.

```
im_thresh = (im >= 145)
plt.imshow(im_thresh, cmap=cm.gray)
```

[image]

Now you might have an additional issue that you have horizontal lines, you can address this by writing on blank paper as suggested. This wasn't exactly your question but I will try to address it anyways (in a naive fashion). You can try a naive solution of using a sobel filter (think of it as the derivative of the image to get the lines), followed by a median filter to get the approximately most common pixel intensity - the size of the filter might have to vary for different digits though. This should clear up some of the lines. For a more rigorous approach try reading up on hough line transform for detecting horizontal lines and try to whiten them out.

This is my very naive approach:

```
from skimage.filters import sobel
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
#Sobel filter reverses intensities so subtracting the result from 1.0 turns it back to the original
plt.imshow(1.0 - median_filter(sobel(im_thresh), [10, 3]), cmap=cm.gray)
```

[image]

You can try cropping automatically afterwards. Honestly I think most neural networks that could recognize MNIST-like digits could recognize the result I posted at the end as well.

Comment: thank you, my  image is between [100-200], but how to detect  low and  high point automaticaly?

Comment: thank you , now it is very serious  help, of course i can assign  1.0 - median_filter(sobel(im_thresh) to any image right?

Comment: Yes. But your median filter might have to vary for different digits, as I wrote.

Comment: that means i should use input  function in python, where i after see histogram, is  should enter  new threshold value, but  from the histogram , i can take  for instance  90% of maximum value of upper bin and  take it as  a threshold can i do it?

Comment: The maximum value of the upper bin is always going to be 255*0.9. I think you need to think in terms of quantiles perhaps? You can either empirically check on different digits, or think of an algorithm yourself after you understand a little bit more. I don't know if there's a "right solution" here. Try some things first....

Comment: happy Easter . god bless  t you

Comment: one question my friend, i can't import median filter

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that

Comment: no reason for sorry, thanks for your help , let me try  a bit later  about code and  i will return in case of any question

Comment: sorry  my friend how to fix this error ? RuntimeError: structure and input must have same dimensionality

Answer (score 0):

Try using skimage package like this. This has inbuilt functions for image processing:

```
from skimage import io

from skimage.restoration import denoise_tv_chambolle
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu


image = io.imread('path/to/your/image', as_gray=True)

# Denoising
denoised_image = denoise_tv_chambolle(image, weight=0.1, multichannel=True)

# Thresholding
threshold = threshold_otsu(denoised_image)
thresholded_image = denoised_image > threshold
```

Comment: sorry i did not get point of this code, could you explain me   a bit more?

Comment: I was trying to share how you can denoise and threshold the image using skimage package..nothing more

Comment: but it is not denosing, question is why this thresholding gives me such result? maybe  image done by pen is difficult to be recognized by computer?

Comment: I think your images should be on plane background. The lines of the page might also be creating an issue